# Select2 only create tag when finished

Tags: jquery-select2-4

I am attempting to use Select2 in tag mode. It appears the `createTag` and `insertTag` functions are called on every key press when entering a new tag. Is it possible to only create a tag when the user selects the new option/tag (either via mouse or keyboard)? I have some processing to do with the tags as they are entered, but only when the user deems them complete.

```
$(this.select).select2({
    tags: true,
    createTag: function (params) {
        console.log(params.term);
        return {
            id: params.term,
            text: params.term,
            newTag: true
        }
    },
    insertTag: function (data, tag) {
        console.log(tag.text);
        data.push(tag);
    }
});
```

This logs every single keystroke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's the simple `change` event which fires when the user has finished entering a tag - listening to that allowed me to do the required processing before the option was selected.